# How to filter jira-cli getIssueList report

Tags: jira, jira-cli

`jira.sh --server http://jira.########.###:8080 --password ######### --action getIssueList --jql "project = SetRix order by Created desc" --user ##### --project SetRix --limit 15 --dateFormat "MM-dd" --outputFormat 2 --suppressId --columns "Key,Summary,Created,Status"`

Above is my jira-cli query, and here is the report:

```
"STR-120","Do not report status for the jobwhen it is terminated","02-13","Done"
"STR-119","timeshift memory leak - high CPU","02-12","To Do"
"STR-118","Timeshift directory per-stream","02-12","To Do"
"STR-117","Restart button needed","02-12","To Do"
"STR-116","Create 'clone' function for presets","02-12","Done"
```

How do I filder the report to only see "To Do" entries?

I do not want to grep, I want to use jira query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the JQL and the output columns, I would say:

```
project = SetRix AND Status = 'To Do' order by Created desc
```

i.e. just explicitly ask for the items that are still `To Do`